# Update route to support two separate calls

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently i have route as below

```
namespace :books
  resources :pages, only: [] do
    post 'lesson'
  end
end
```

Path:    `DB/DB_id/user/user_id/books/pages/page_id/lesson`

How do i update the route to support following path?

`DB/DB_id/user/user_id/books`

I am not passing any book_id. just want to list all books

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namespace :books
  get "/", to: "books#index"
  resources :pages, only: [] do
    post 'lesson'
  end
end
```

Of course if you eventually do want to access individual books, you'll want to make books a resource so you can easily add routes later.

```
resources :books, only: [:index] do
  resources :pages, only: [] do
    post 'lesson'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks eiko. i thought of adding another resource for events but your solution is cool